# Trouble getting Linux Self Hosted Agents with VMSS to work ideally

Tags: azure, ubuntu, azure-devops

I wanted to create a Self Hosted Agent pool for my CICD pipelines using Ubuntu VMSS.
Although the process seems to be unclear and I stubbled upon several hurdles during this process.

Hi fellow devs,
I'm failry new to the Azure ecosystem, recently transitioned for AWS for my new client. We wanted to use VMSS for for build agents for our CICD pipelines.
Steps I took to create the VMSS Agent pool:

Got a fresh Ubuntu VM from the Infra team (I'm not yet allowed to create the VM, as public resources are not allowed and I don't have contributor role to any network resources due to strict security policies)

Used https://github.com/actions/runner-images to get the packages needed for Ubuntu 22.04

As the packer requires a builder, I used "null" builder to set it as localhost ref: https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/docs/builders/null (It was way difficult to figure it out the 1st time)

I had to modify the .pkr.hcl file to pick my provisioners.

I could not understand the use of /opt/hostedtoolcache folder (which I did later)

Then I created a VM Image from this VM and asked the Infra team to create the VMSS for me with Private endpoint and subnet integration.

I created an Agent pool in Azure DevOps "UbuntuVMSSPoC" and added the VMSS agent and was able to set it up just fine.

I tried a CI job for node application which had a "NodeTool@0" task,
[image: Job Initialisation params]

but when this pipeline was executed on the VMSS I got the following error
[image: Directory access error]

I can see that the agent runs as a user "AzDevOps" but then why it doesn't have access to /opt/hostedtoolcache?

To solve this I added a Custom Script extension to my VMSS to grant user "AzDevOps" write access to /opt/hostedtoolcache, but, it did not work as the user doesn't exist when this script is executed.
[image: Custom script error]

The last option I had was to do a chmod 777 on the /opt/hostedtoolcache directory which solved the problem but not a solution that is ideal.

Based on this I have a few questions:

Am I doing something wrong?

As per my understanding, the /opt/hostedtoolcache is used for caching the tools installed during pipeline execution, but after every run the VM gets reimaged, which means I loose the newly cached tool, which doesn't make sense to me

Shall the AgentToolsDirectory be mounted as NFS to all my VMSS agents?

Why there's no proper documentation citing the whole process?